# Proguard Android do not obfuscate anything except few classes

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I want to force ProGuard not to obfuscate ANYTHING except only a few classes.

How can this be done? Please provide actual sample code as I've looked online and haven't found something similar.

Comment: put those classes in separate package.  keep all the other packages.

Comment: Its not that easy in my project to move these stuff around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who care this is how its done:

-keep class
  !com.mypackage.classA,
  !com.mypackage.classB { *; }

etc...

Comment: Doesn't work for me ;( Maybe things have changed since 2012. I filed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59248681/proguard-r8-negate-operator-not-working-to-keep-anything-except-certain-packag?noredirect=1&lq=1